# Porting IPv4 Application to Dualstack IPv4/IPv6

Tags: ipv6

Actually I'm porting an IPv4 server application to a dualstack IPv4/IPv6 application on Linux.

The basic function I have solved by using:

```
serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
serv_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
...
bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
...
listen(sock, 5);
...
newsock = accept(syn->sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

I can connect with IPv4 and IPv6 and use the connections. But when I want to get the IP with:

```
switch(data->sa_family) {
   case AF_INET:
   inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((struct sockaddr_in*)data)->sin_addr), buffer, size);
   break;
   case AF_INET6:
   inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)data)->sin6_addr), buffer, size);
   break;

   default:
   buffer[0] = '?';
   buffer[1] = 0;
}
```

I always get an IPv6 address as expected, or if it is a IPv4 connection something like ::ffff:127.0.0.1

What do I have to change, to display as a plain old IPv4 address in the form of 127.0.0.1 (without the ::ffff:-prefix)?

Thanks
Teddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can go:

1. Just strip off this `::ffff:` from the beginning, if present, and take it as indicator for IPv4.
2. Use two distinct sockets. There are OS around there which do not support IPv4 and 6 via one socket (IOW, they have `V6ONLY` always enabled). Especially, WinXP does so.

   Then there is only one thing you can do:

   - Use `getaddrinfo()` with `AI_PRIVATE` for getting all local socket addresses you can have
   - Use them all to create a listening socket and enable `V6ONLY` immediately, if possible
   - Keep their descriptors in an array and use `select()` et al to determine which of them to call `accept()`.

   Sounds more complicated than it really is...

Answer (score 3):

There's a macro to help, but only half the battle:

```
  if (IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED(&serv_addr.sin6_addr)) {
        struct sockaddr_in tmpsa;
        tmpsa.sin_family = AF_INET;
        tmpsa.sin_port = 0;
        tmpsa.sin_addr.s_addr = serv_addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr32[3];
  /* process IPv4 address in tmpsa ... */
        inet_ntop (AF_INET, &tmpsa.sin_addr, buffer, size);
  } else {
  /* process IPv6 address in serv_addr.. */
        inet_ntop (AF_INET6, &serv_addr.sin6_addr, buffer, size);
  }
```

Minor modifications may be required depending upon platform, here is use GNU standards.

Answer (score 1):

You request that IPv4 mapped connections be presented as if they're actually IPv4 with code like the following:

```
int cli = accept( server, NULL, NULL );
int addrform = AF_INET;
setsockopt( cli, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADDRFORM, &addrform, sizeof(addrform) );
```

This would need to be done on for each new client socket.  It will fail for IPv6 connections; you can either ignore that or check first and only call it if you're working with an IPv4-mapped client.

Once that's done you can call `getpeername()` to get the client address information in the preferred format rather than getting that as part of the call to `accept()`.